# Why IBKR API keeps showing ___ object has no attribute ___?

Tags: api, attributes, trading, interactive-brokers, tws

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSFB7.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYkPX.jpg)

extra information below:

1. I think the connection is established (I opened TWS and did the right settings for API)
2. I made the right virtual environment with anaconda
3. I move all the relevant TWS files to the folder and set up the terminal with the virtual environment there.

Answer (score 0):

Your `historicalData` method accesses an instance variable named `data` that hasn't been created. Assuming `data` is a dictionary, you can create it by adding a line to `__init__`:

```
def __init__(self):
    EClient.__init__(self, self)
    data = {}
```